# Converting UNIX timestamp using ctime

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have a unix time stamp as follows

```
  char timestamp[100];
  strcpy(timestamp,"701729943");
  time_t timeval=ctime(timestamp);
  printf("Time %s",timeval);
```

If the check the value of the timestamp in the online unix time convertor it shows 27th march 1992, but if the check the program's output it shows feb 25,1996. How to rectify this?

Comment: First clean up all the warnings your compiler is giving you about mismatched types w/o casts and see if you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `ctime` the wrong way around: it expects a pointer to a `time_t` and returns a string, whereas you're passing it a string and expect it to return a `time_t`. Does your compiler not warn you about that?

Anyway, it is meant to be used this way:

```
time_t timeval = 701729943;
printf("Time %s", ctime(&timeval));
```

If you only have the UNIX timestamp as a string, use `strtoul` or `atoi` to so to make a `time_t` from it, then do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate your response.